# jQuery Drag from a List (without removing element) and Drop into another List

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

How can I have two lists (div or table elements) in which I can drag & drop items from one to the other (I think jQuery droppable does this), but **without actually removing it** from the source list?

Example:

```
List1    List2
 AAA     111
 BBB     555
 CCC     999
 DDD     777
```

Now I'm dragging BBB from the left to the right between "555" and "999". Result (see how BBB is now in *both*:

```
List1    List2
 AAA     111
 BBB     555
 CCC     BBB
 DDD     999
         777
```

Answer (score 1):

you should look at [jquery sortable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable). [connectWith](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#option-connectWith) option is used to connect with another sortable list so you can drop it to that list.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable)... it's not EXACTLY what you want, but I think it will get you on the right track. The example performs similarly to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
         $(this);
         $(ui.draggable.**clone()**).appendTo($(this));
      }
```